# How to install Linux on a machine where the network card is too new for the drivers to be included in any distributions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, nic

I recently had the problem that my new HP 15s-fq2001ni laptop has a Realtek RTL8821CE-M wifi NIC.
I wanted to install Ubuntu on the laptop, so I downloaded the latest ubuntu 20.10 iso image, and used Rufus to write the iso image to a USB memory stick on my older DELL laptop which was running Windows.
After I installed the new Ubuntu OS on the HP laptop, I noticed that the network card did not work.
After some googling, I found that the RTL8821CE wifi NIC is quite new, and the distros do not come with a kernel that has built in drivers for this NIC.

I found that the driver had been written for the NIC, and could be found here: https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

Quite relieved, I downloaded the driver source and copied it to the HP laptop with a USB memory stick.
Bad news - I ran make in the directory where I extracted the source code on the HP laptop, and I see that  gcc is not installed.
apt-get install gcc fails of course because the HP laptop cannot connect to the internet without a NIC.
Also the driver needs DKMS to install the kernel module (which can similarly not be downloaded with apt).

More bad news, just copying the relevant .deb file for gcc across with USB doesn't work because there are so many dependencies that I would spend hours iterating through a frustrating process of seeing that the HP is missing a library, downloading it on the DELL laptop, copying it to USB, then moving the USB across to the HP, and using "dpkg -i' to install the .deb file, only to find that it depends on another library that I don't have (this is why package managers like apt were invented)

next I tried to use apt-mirror to mirror the whole ubuntu repository (106 GB download) on an external HDD by booting my DELL laptop into a live version of ubuntu and then using apt-mirror to build the repository on the external HDD. I then mounted the external HDD on the HP laptop and changed /etc/apt/sources.list to see the packages on the external HDD as a repository..

deb file:/media/[user]/mirror

This didn't work because it turns out that there are bugs in apt-mirror which cause it not to download all the files necessary to build a complete mirror.
I tried fixing the apt-mirror code, which worked to an extent, but there were so many bugs that it was taking me too long and I wonder if there is an easier way....?

Comment: Read [Linux from scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/); you could use  [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC) to compile your driver, then once it is running install GCC

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch this may have been quicker than my solution

Answer (score 3):

So now many days down the line, I finally found a solution:

1. install ubuntu on the HP laptop
2. boot a live instance of ubuntu on the other DELL laptop using the "Try Ubuntu" live option when booting the Ubuntu iso image
3. mount the external HDD on this live instance of Ubuntu on the second DELL laptop
4. download the driver source code to the external HDD
5. install GCC and DKMS on this live instance of Ubuntu on the second DELL laptop

sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install dkms

6. copy `/usr` (containing the compiled GCC and dkms binaries) from this live instance of Ubuntu on the second DELL laptop to the external HDD
7. boot a live instance of ubuntu on the new HP laptop using the "Try Ubuntu" live option when booting the Ubuntu iso image
8. mount the external HDD on the HP laptop on the live instance of Ubuntu
   (even though the laptop already has Ubuntu installed on its internal HDD -
   you need to do this because you cannot overwrite the files in `/usr` when the installed version of Ubuntu
   is running because they will be in use)
9. mount the internal HDD of the HP laptop on the live instance of Ubuntu
10. copy the contents of `/usr` on the external HDD to the internal HDD of the HP
11. reboot the HP and boot into the installed instance of Ubuntu on the internal HDD (after removing the USB boot media)
12. mount the external HDD on the installed instance of Ubuntu on the HP
13. in the network driver source code directory on the external HDD, compile the driver source with "make" (using the GCC binaries copied in step 10)
14. install the kernel driver module using "make install" (which uses dkms)
15. NIC comes up and you can connect to the wifi